# How to take a screenshot of your canvas in java and save it on permanent storage?

Tags: java, paint

I am creating a simple paint application in java. I have a button that should save the drawing on the canvas when clicked by the user. How can I do that?

Comment: Check out [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) for a handy class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to paint it to an offline buffer, then save it to disk.

```
BufferedImage offImage = (BufferedImage)createImage( getWidth(), getHeight());
Graphics2D    g2       = offImage.createGraphics();
g2.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
g2.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING   , RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY );
paintComponent( g2 );
paintChildren( g2 );
ImageIO.write( offImage, "png", "snapshot.png" );
```

Comment: Don't invoke paintComponent() and paintChildren() separate, just invoke paint() on the component being used as the canvas. Some people have also suggested it is more efficient to use `print(....)`